# MySQL server connection is not working in c# .net

Tags: c#, mysql

In web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial             Catalog=uday;User Id=root;Password=mysql@niperhyd" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In CS file:

```
string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
connection.Open();
lblMsg.Text = "connection established";
connection.Close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it's not working_ ? You get any error or exception message after your `connection.Open()` line? Did you debug your code? Are you sure your `connectionString` is right?

Comment: What you are getting upon attempting to connect ?

Answer (score 1):

From [`MySQL ConnectionString`](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

**1.** You need to use `Database` instead of `Initial Catalog`.

**2.** You need to use `Server` instead of `Data Source`.

Try This:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=uday;
    User Id=root;Password=mysql@niperhyd" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<add name="connstring" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=uday;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=root;Password=mysql@niperhyd" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```